# CSS doesnt Load on custom theme - Magento2

Tags: magento2

I created a custom theme and now NO css is loading anymore..
Yesterday I had the same custom theme with **Luma / blank** as its parent and it did load, now doesn't load at all.
[image: No CSS]

I removed cache and everything but it seems to be not working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be your `pub/static` files are not there.

fire below command from your magento root from terminal .

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Indeed my CSS files were missing in "pub/static/frontend/vendorname/themename/de-CH/". Now I delete all these files again and run the command. Strangely it now created a folder "en-US" in "pub/static/frontend/vendorname/themename/".. in the CSS Folder are ONLY ".less" files tho.. My website still doesnt load the css..

Comment: check browser console for error

Comment: What do you mean by browser console?

Comment: Created now a "new" Theme and still, the css didnt get created in "pub/static/frontend/vendorname/theme/de_CH/ ....

Comment: check parent theme as luma other wise it will take blanck theme

Comment: luma is parent theme of my custom theme..

Comment: Had to click "Flush static files cache" and it did work..

Comment: If my answer help you some how then mark as accepted , so other users take benifit